# What technology is used for authorities to send emergency alerts to mobile phone users?

Tags: wireless, wifi, cellphone, protocol

Do modern-day protocols that our mobile phones run on eg. CDMA/GSM, 3G or 4G have a emergency break-in/broadcast protocol for authorities to issue warnings to the public? In the recent case in Hawaii of a false missile attack alert, users were [reported to have an unusual vibration and/or sound](http://edition.cnn.com/2018/01/13/us/hawaii-false-alert-how-process/index.html) on their mobile phones when receiving the SMS alert warning of an incoming missile attack.

Does the each of the wireless specification(s) mention of an emergency communication intervention feature that is present in almost all modern phones running Android, Apple or Blackberry, or was this delivered over plain old vanilla SMS? (I would imagine cost being a factor here, as well as difficulty in receiving messages on phones without a subscription plan, eg. roaming phones. Secondly, a message of such unprecedented importance should trigger a more urgent signal to the user, rather than just a benign sound or simple buzz. Which brings up the next question, can this be emergency warning messages be delivered to 'roaming' phones too?)

Perhaps, there is a built-in software equivalent Internet protocol baked into the respective mobile OSes that could also beam an alert should the device be connected to the Internet in another way, for example, via Wi-Fi?

What are your thoughts?

Comment: Take a look at the wireless specifications and find out?

Comment: I know, but dont have the time to dig deep. Google showed up nothing too.

Comment: The US system is https://www.fcc.gov/consumers/guides/wireless-emergency-alerts-wea ; there is nothing comparable in IP and it would probably be a nightmare to build.

Comment: @dim Life saving features are usually hidden until one needs it.

Comment: Public specifications can be remarkably hard to find even if they aren't truly "hidden". But it's worth a bit more googling. e.g. https://www.google.com/patents/US20110070861 or https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/part-10

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about EE. Link: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @Andyaka I beg to differ.  It is a "a communication scheme", at the very least, as per guidelines

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing hidden about what happened in Hawaii. It's called [Cell Broadcast](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_Broadcast).
Phones pick this up since they support these messages.
[There is even a tickbox for them.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202743)

The sound and vibration isn't unusual, it always plays maximum volume and has a sound designed to be heard. It works even in loud area's due to using unnatural frequencies.

Cell broadcast is being evaluated as replacement for air sirens in my country, the Netherlands, but it's hasn't proven to be very effective. There are still a lot of unsupported phones and lots of delay in some area for some reason.

Suggesting the internet protocol has "hidden break-in" features is straight up conspiracy stuff. The internet is public, [you can read the specification on the internet.](http://www.ietf.org/) 
Some devices might have hidden features, but they usually don't stay hidden forever.

I'd recommend asking further question about the internet at [SU](https://superuser.com/), [SF](https://stackoverflow.com/) or [NE](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Why the conspiracy? When I say hidden, Im usually referring to obscure features of a technical specification that is drafted but often overlooked because nobody cares about it until it becomes necessary. Not related to conspiracies

Comment: @Nederealm So you mean, "rarely used features"?

Comment: Yes, like you don't normally mention of a fire extinguisher in your car, until you potentially need to use it, right?

Comment: Or until the fire extinguisher overheats and explodes in what would have otherwise been a containable fire, which seems to be the point you're getting at here - that rarely used safety features can have their own risks.

Answer (score 1):

Unusual sounds/vibration can be explained by the unusual type of message being sent. Broadcast messages are usually sent using SMS-CB mechanism (instead of SMS-PP). Additionally, high-importance alerts are often sent with [SMS_FLASH](https://archive.clickatell.com/developers/api-docs/flash-(popup)-messaging-advanced-message-send/) type, instructing the handset to display the message on the screen immediately, rather than storing it in the inbox. Since most users don't receive such messages often, they have no idea what kind of alert their phone has for it.

Answer (score -4):

Based on the comments, I found most of the answers to my question via both the [FCC website](https://www.fcc.gov/consumers/guides/wireless-emergency-alerts-wea) and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_Emergency_Alerts) on the topic. As well as a [patent](https://www.google.com/patents/US20110070861) describing the protocol in detail. Thanks to all those who commented.